Which is the largest $p$ such that if $f\in L^1(\mathbb{T})$ and $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty |\hat{f}(n)|^p<\infty$ then $f$ is continuous?
According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_algebra, if a function $f\in L^1(\mathbb{T})$ is in the Wiener algebra, i.e., $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty |\hat{f}(n)|<\infty$, then $f$ is continuous. Clearly, if we only assume that $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty |\hat{f}(n)|^2<\infty$ then $f$ need not be continuous. My question is what happens in the middle, which is the largest $p\in[1,2]$ such that, if $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty |\hat{f}(n)|^p<\infty$, then $f$ is continuous?

The largest such $p$ is $1$.
Below is an example of an element of $L^1(\mathbb R/\mathbb Z)$ which has no continuous representative and whose Fourier transform is in $\ell^q(\mathbb Z)$ for every $q>1$.

Consider the function $f:\mathbb R/\mathbb Z\to\mathbb C$ given by $f(t+\mathbb Z)=e^{\pi it}$ for every $t\in[0,1)$.
The function $f$ is integrable on $\mathbb R/\mathbb Z$, as it is bounded and almost everywhere continuous, and its equivalence class in $L^1(\mathbb R/\mathbb Z)$ has no representative that is continuous at $0+\mathbb Z$ because $0+\mathbb Z=1+\mathbb Z$ and
$$\lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac 1h\int_{0}^{0+h}f(t+\mathbb Z)\,dt=1\qquad\text{and}\qquad\lim_{h\to 0^-}\frac 1h\int_{1}^{1+h}f(t+\mathbb Z)\,dt=-1.$$
And for every $q>1$, the Fourier transform of $f$ satisfies
$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}|\hat f(n)|^q
&=\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}\left|\int_{0}^{1}e^{\pi it}e^{-2\pi int}\,dt\right|^q\\
&=\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}\left|\frac{e^{\pi i(1-2n)}}{\pi i(1-2n)}-\frac{1}{\pi i(1-2n)}\right|^q\leq\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}\left(\frac{2}{\pi|1-2n|}\right)^q<+\infty.
\end{align*}$$
